# SQLServer2005: Save complete results of query in a file for some long text data types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, file, text, ssms

Lets say a have a table

```
t (id int, someVeryLongText text)
```

and want to store the result of a query:

```
select someVeryLongText from t where id = 1
```

in the file.

In Managemant Studio when I select **Tools->Options->QueryResults** and choose **Results to File** It seems that only the first 8192 characters are written to the file.

Is there an option to force it to include all the data from a text data type field without the size limit?

Answer (score 1):

Try `SET TEXTSIZE <size_in_bytes>` to the maximum amount of text you want to be retrieved.